# How to pass date value from calendar to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working on a task issue report project. I have a calendar, when I click select date, I couldn't pass date value in to controller in Redmine. I am using Bootstrap datepicker.

```
<div id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" data-provide='datepicker' : hidden="true">
  <input type="text" class='datepicker' name="reportdate" onchange = "this.form.submit();"
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Is there a form to submit?

Answer (score 0):

Here I add a very basic form submit with date picker using bootstrap, you must get an idea form here.

```
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :start_at %>
      <div class="datepicker" class="input-group date">
        <%= f.text_field :start_at, :class => "form-control" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```